Horror town with a dark secret trope
I saw a movie on SYFY as a young teen probably 2010ish
In the movie, a teenager goes to some village or town that is surrounded by woods. 
The town turns out to have a curse where the town has to sacrifice a person to a monster or the monster will start to kill the people of the town. 
During the movie they try to kill the monster but fail and the ending scene is the teenager that found the town along with a girl from the town escapes through the woods but the girl from the town can't leave due to some kind of barrier that is part of the curse.

OK, I might as well throw my hat in the ring... I think this is actually Ogre from 2008. It all fits:

Mainly about a teen and his girlfriend (there are 2 other teens, but they die early on);
They stumble upon a town in the woods;
The town sacrifices a person each year to a huge, bad-CGI ogre;
The town is surrounded by an invisible barrier (it's basically stuck in the past);
Teen and his girlfriend say goodbye to a local girl in the end and escape, but the local girl doesn't remain behind, she ascends to heaven because they vanquished the ogre's curse;
Aired on the Sci-Fi Channel in 2008 and Syfy International in 2010.

Here's the trailer:




You sir, are a true hero

@DellLamartiniere Glad to help! :) Don't forget to approve the answer (if it's the right one) by clicking on the check mark next to it, this effectively resolves your question. And welcome to M&TV!

This sounds somewhat like the M. Night Shyamalan movie The Village. It contains a village surrounded by woods. There are monsters in the woods that will attack if anyone ventures into the woods. Towards the end of the movie, a blind girl, followed by a mentally handicapped boy from the village, ventures through the woods and come to a barrier wall.

He is wearing one of the "monster" costumes that the adults in the village secretly use. The girl fights with him and accidentally kills him, not knowing it is him.

A few elements are definitely missing:

there are multiple monsters instead of just one
no human sacrifice is required
the villagers don't directly try to kill the monsters, though I seem to remember a fight when the monsters attack the village

Here is the trailer for The Village:




I thought it might have been the village too but sadly it wasnt. Appreciate the effort though.

In the same vein, as the other answer, it also sounds a lot like M. Night Shyamalan's TV adaptation of Blake Crouch's Wayward Pines.


In the first season, Ethan Burke (Matt Dillon) is a U.S. Secret
  Service agent investigating the disappearance of two fellow agents in
  the mysterious small town of Wayward Pines, Idaho. Ethan awakens
  from a car accident unable to contact the outside world and unable to
  leave. He finds one of the agents dead and the other, his former lover
  Kate Hewson (Carla Gugino), settled down in the seemingly idyllic
  town. But the inhabitants of Wayward Pines are trapped there by an
  electrified fence and set of rules enforced by the strict Sheriff
  Arnold Pope (Terrence Howard) and any attempt to escape is punished
  by a public execution known as a "reckoning". Ethan works to
  discover the truth.


It's a town everyone is trapped in and is embedded in woodlands and mountains.
It does have creatures called, "Abbies" outside the town and three get into the town during the first season (but I don't want to spoil so I will not say more).
The towns perimeter is secured by a giant electric fence.
Two characters pretend to be romantically involved in attempts to try and escape.
And this leads to a "reckoning", which is "human sacrifice" or public execution (but the Abbies are not meant to eat those murdered, despite that they do attack people, when in contact)

However, this series airs on FOX, not SYFY, it's a summer series, not a movie, and it has yet to be determined if there will be a third season, so perhaps The Village is the answer you are looking for...
Opening Credits:




It's possible you might be thinking of the 2010 film, The Shrine. It features a journalist and her friends who are investigating the disappearance of several people in the fictional Polish village of Alvania. It's not surrounded by woods, but the woods nearby are filled with an impenetrable fog, and they learn that the reason is that there is a malevolent force associated with a statue (and a long ago curse) in the fog that embeds an evil spirit within those who view it. The victims of the force have to be taken down by the local religious authorities and a metal mask is embedded into their face (with spikes for the eyes) to ensure that the evil is sealed away. What does not match is that there is only one survivor, and no villager prevented from escaping.

Trailer



